# Symfony 2 Formtype query builder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem and with Symfony 2 form type and I cant seem to get the hang of it. 
I have a device which should be put into a category. This works fine. I get a selection box with all the category Ids.

```
DeviceType.php:

->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Please choose a category',
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'MSelectorBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'id'))
```

However the category name etc are stored in a different entity which allow me to translate them in different languages with a OneToMany Relationship like this:

```
Category.php: 

    class Category
    {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $active;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\M\SelectorBundle\Entity\CategoryTranslations", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist", "remove"} ,orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $categoryTranslations;
```

Now instead of showing the id which is non-descriptive I'd like to show the category name in a specific language however I cant get this working.

```
CategoryTranslations.php:
/**
 * CategoryTranslations
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categoryTranslations")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CategoryTranslations
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=10)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", length=10)
     */
    private $category_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lang", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $lang;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=300)
     */
    private $name;
```

I have tried query builder and array collections and I haven't been able to solve this. I new to symfony so hopefully someone can point me into the right direction. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entity` field is not suitable for what you want. I suggest you use the `collection` field and pass it a [`ChoiceList`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php). The `ChoiceList` constructor accepts two arrays, one for values, the other for labels.

The only problem you may have is after form submission, when you try to map the value back to an entity. Just be sure to pass your entity IDs as the values.

Comment: I didn't know about the choice_list. I ended up using a SimpleChoiseList. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `'property' => 'id'` to `'property' => 'name'` also you will need to implement getter and setter in you entity class